# How to delegate Spock Mock behavior to a real object with argument

Tags: spock

I have a class `Table` with a method `getDataFromTable` which takes one argument. Under the hood, `Table::getDataFromTable` just delegates to `TableConfig::getTableData` which further delegates to `ConfigDO::getTableMap. How can I have my Spock Mock of` Table`delegate this method call with its argument to the real instance of`ConfigDO`? I.e. I want

```java
getDataFromTable(argument) >> configDo.getTableDataMap().get(argument)
```

Classes involved:

```java
package com.place.core;

import org.springframework.stereotyp.Component;
import com.place.configuration.TableConfig;

@Component
public class Table {
    private final TableConfig tableConfig;
    
    public Table(TableConfig config) {
        this.tableConfig = config;
    }

    public String getDataFromTable(String tableName) {
        return tableConfig.getTableData(tableName);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.place.configuration;

import com.place.representation.ConfigDO;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TableConfig {
    private final ConfigDO configDo;

    public TableConfig(ConfigDO config) {
        this.configDo = config;
    }

    public String getTableData(String tableName) {
        return configDo.getTableMap().get(tableName);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.place.representation;

import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
public class ConfigDO {
    private final Map<String, String> tableDataMap;
}
```

Minimal spec:

```java
class TableTest extends Specification {
    def configDo = new ConfigDO()

    def mockTableConfig = Mock(TableConfig) {
        // What I feel like I'd like to do: take the argument from TableConfig::getTableData and pass it to the Map::get call
        getTableData(argument) >> configDo.getTableDataMap().get(argument)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Help us help you by learning [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At least share the rest of the specification, how are `foo` and `baz` initialized?

Comment: Added an MCVE .

Comment: Sorry, that is not an MCVE. It is just a sloppy mess of pseudo code. For example, `Foo` does not have a `bar` method, but `getThing` instead. Do you ever run the code in isolation before copying and pasting it, in order to make sure that it actually does anything meaningful? And how is anyone supposed to know what `@Data` and `@Configuration` do? Last but not least: What is `quux()` supposed to do, if `quux` is just a map? Give your questions some more love, for heaven's sake. Not for me or anyone else, but for your own benefit, getting better answers faster.

Comment: Apologies. I am having a hard time distilling several hundred lines of code from work down to something that's publicly consumable yet retains the relevant parts. I assumed that Spring Boot's `@Configuration` and Lombok's `@Data` annotations were common enough that they didn't need specifying, but that was evidently unwarranted. I have tried again.

Comment: Sound like you want a `Spy` and not a `Mock`. From the example it doesn't really look like you need it at all and could just use `Foo` as-is, but I guess you omitted the other parts. Also where should the values for `Baz` `quux` map come from in your spec?

Comment: I thought that he might want a spy, too. But I hate guessing, I want to analyze. The "M" in MCVE means "minimal", not "less than minimal". The latter is still the case.  Where does this desire to hide information come from? Is it not more difficult to remove essential stuff than to actually keep it? Again, you keep us asking and guessing, because you are too "code-stingy". How about full classes with package names, imports, initialisation, instead of omitting it? Why make it tedious for the volunteers who are trying to help you?

Comment: The practice to prepare an MCVE is a basic developer skill. Try to learn it, it is worth the effort and not very difficult. Just like cycling, any programmer can learn it. It will be a very rewarding experience, especially because it facilitates debugging and also - almost magically - gets you good answers much faster than by playing the information hiding and guessing game with your fellow developers. I am not angry at you (annoyed maybe), but trying to encourage you to learn something useful. 

Comment: I cannot share proprietary code on a public forum. That's what makes creating an MCVE difficult in this case. I'm not trying to be difficult.

Comment: Ok, expanded the MCVE. In the process I realized there's another intervening class, which may have contributed to the confusion (in addition to just ...not M :) ).

Comment: Does this work for you ? `getDataFromTable(_) >> { configDo.getTableDataMap().get(it[0])} `

Comment: The alternative would be to use a Spy `def mockTableConfig = Spy(TableConfig, constructorArgs: [configDo ])` or to just use the `TableConfig` directly, as this didn't include any motivation for actually replacing it with a mock/spy.

Comment: The motivation for not using a real `TableConfig` is because this isn't a `@SpringBootTest` (or any other type of Spring Boot test that stands up an application context). I've had problems before trying to use Spring stereotype beans in non-Spring Boot tests. `TableConfig` also has several of its own dependencies which I am not trying to test right now, so I would like to isolate it.

Your first suggestion did not work. I get "No such property: it for class TableTest"

Comment: Yes, but at least from what we can see it is just a pojo. If you don't actually want to mock out some of its functions, why not just construct it by hand, no need to use `@SpringBootTest`, unless it is way more complex than what we can see. Also how many different calls to `getDataFromTable` do you actually expect, do you really need a generic thing instead of just having one `getDataFromTable(_) >> "some value"` in the method that uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is but much closer to an MCVE now. I had to add an initialiser for the map, but that was OK. Next time, make sure you post something others can actually compile and run in a meaningful way. As for your remark about confidential code: An MCVE is not your original code, but a simplified, minimal but working version of it. You can rename all packages, classes and methods to your heart's content in order to not resemble the original code anymore, as long as the structure is still similar enough to reproduce your problem. Just copy and strip down the original project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated simplified Groovy versions of your Java classes without any references to Spring or Lombok, because the latter are irrelevant for your question.

- The first problem is your method stubbing syntax for the mock in general.
- The second is that you need to learn how to [access mock method arguments](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/all_in_one.html#_computing_return_values) when stubbing.
- The third is that you tried to stub method `getDataFromTable`, which does not exist in `TableConfig`. You cannot stub a `Table` method in `TableConfig`. Please be more careful to actually stub methods which really exist in the class to be mocked/stubbed.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76038114

import spock.lang.Specification

class TableTest extends Specification {
  def configDo = new ConfigDO()
  def mockTableConfig = Mock(TableConfig) {
    getTableData(_) >> { args -> configDo.tableDataMap[args[0]] }
  }

  def test() {
    given:
    def table = new Table(mockTableConfig)

    expect:
    table.getDataFromTable('foo') == 'Hello world!'
    table.getDataFromTable('bar') == 'These are just test data.'
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76038114

class Table {
  private final TableConfig tableConfig

  Table(TableConfig config) {
    this.tableConfig = config
  }

  String getDataFromTable(String tableName) {
    return tableConfig.getTableData(tableName)
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76038114

class TableConfig {
  private final ConfigDO configDo

  TableConfig(ConfigDO config) {
    this.configDo = config
  }

  String getTableData(String tableName) {
    return configDo.getTableMap().get(tableName)
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76038114

class ConfigDO {
  private final Map<String, String> tableDataMap = [
    foo: 'Hello world!',
    bar: 'These are just test data.'
  ]

  Map<String, String> getTableDataMap() {
    return tableDataMap
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJyFUsFO4zAQvecrZk9JJLBAi3ZRRXtZtNoLy4HeqgqZdBIMiZ21py0S6r_vxHHSpC1wsz3z5r3nebXMXmWBsELhMruuHivpCK1wxAWzQZuXZiv-_fxx8f368vIqilRVG0vgapO9ilLqQjzUmKlcZZKU0VGUldI5mMunEufoCPCNUK8cjNrgPQLmzCEzOlfFrYEpaNzCr_Z6n6ShXjGNn9VWuO2OX5LBU-pnARRI_vVWkkweU5jN4B2kLRycz3oaQV3LnawXTXVxsVzCjifsokBJrDrpp6oN6ok_-loDD1o9W3IgMI18L76xW2pxHiNYXkP725qqBca5MXEK0ynEf7AsDWyNLVff4k8xT9IGzPwZHbI_hJc1_3IjGlbcLGLvZTdahDdTW7WRhJArLUsYfirtz438lmvYkI1-mp6VEzRaStvQ_eIDWaULOJIf3j30r6ywG2iR1lYPZYjRNveAE96ChmOHXZb65ffe2kpy0DCyN8jlR972-r7w1YevA3H2krS5feisl3Zsi8E3LeFZEDODYapZ8cKzc74mB9k68wUO0eSLAC0bq6eYhr69jRMrDLXg6D8OnWyw).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Questions about your points: 1) what was wrong about my syntax (other than that I didn't know the syntax to achieve what I wanted)? 2) Thank you for that link. I was looking for things like "capture", so I did not come across that section of the documentation. 3) This is likely a result of trying to hand-recreate the code in question in an MVCE (and my inexperience in doing so). I'll correct that in my original question.

Comment: Sorry, if my comment was imprecise. (1) I meant `getTableData(argument)` instead of `getTableData(_)`, `getTableData(_ as String)` or `getTableData('foo')` according to the [argument constraints syntax](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints). I.e., I was referring to the left hand side of `>>`. To the right hand side, I was referring to in (2).